# Return last id and count of id

Tags: mysql

I have this data on a table called *messages (id, category, user)* :

```
1 1 aaa
2 2 aaa
3 3 aaa
4 1 bbb
5 2 aaa
6 1 ccc
7 2 aaa
8 3 ddd
```

I'd like to return only one row, with the number of row for the category 1 (in the example **3**) and the last id of that category (in the example **6**).

How can i do it with a MySql query?

Comment: If you really want to get the ACTUAL row number, do NOT use count. Also if one of your IDs is deleted, Count cant give you a wrong value. Rather you've got to use a new variable. But the issue is how you are really going to implement this. If it's through a PHP function like mysql_query(), you can't use multiple SQL statements in the query. So first you need to state how you're going to implement this.

Comment: "Also if one of your IDs is deleted, Count cant give you a wrong value" ? What? can you give an example of this "bug"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select count(*), max(id) from mytab where category = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT category, COUNT(category) AS counter, MAX(id) AS max FROM messages
GROUP BY  category
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(id), MAX(id) FROM tblName
WHERE category = 1
GROUP BY category
```